# node-sass and sass-loader - Module build failed: TypeError: this.getResolve is not a function at Object.loader

Tags: vue.js, npm, node-sass, sass-loader

I am simply trying to follow a tutorial which tells me to install both node-sass and sass-loader. When I do I get the following error:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                       6:21:28 PM
 error  in ./src/components/TodoList.vue

Module build failed: TypeError: this.getResolve is not a function
    at Object.loader (C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\todo-vue\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:52:26)

 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-3de47834","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/components/TodoList.vue 4:14-377 13:3-17:5 14:22-385
 @ ./src/components/TodoList.vue
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

My package.json file

```
{
  "name": "todo-vue",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "author": "Jethro Hazelhurst <j.hazelhurst1994@gmail.com>",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^2.2.0",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.12.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

My Vue file where I am setting `<style lang="scss">`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="todo-input" placeholder="What needs to be done">
        Todo list goes here
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'todo-list',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">

</style>
```

No idea where I am going wrong here.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Having the same problem after trying to use SCSS (`<style lang="scss">`) instead of stylus (`<style lang="stylus">`) in a Vue single file component.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have `"webpack": "^3.12.0"` and `"sass-loader": "^8.0.0"`, which I believe is incompatible (as discussed in [this Github issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/753)).

To solve the problem, either upgrade `webpack` to version `4` or downgrade `sass-loader` to version `7` (which, personally, is what I did).

Answer (score 4):

Downgrading from sass-loader 8.0.0 to 7.3.1 fixed it for me on new builds with Webpack 4.4.0.

**Resources:**

Github Issue Tracker: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/761

Github Solution: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/761#issuecomment-554608680

Answer (score 2):

new fish here, doing the same tutorial!

At the beginning after "npm run dev", there are warnings like
sass-loader@^x.x.x found but y.y.y expected.
webpack@^x.x.x found but y.y.y expected.

for those searching npm downgrade commands:

1. uninstall
   e.g.

> npm uninstall sass-loader

2. install the expected version (change y.y.y to your expected version)

> npm install sass-loader@^y.y.y --save-dev

I ran this in my project root folder, and then the tutorial worked (however, under localhost:3000/todo)